# floated images mess up parent div's width

Tags: html, css

I can't understand this. Please take a look on this page:
http://jonaseklundh.se/test/imgfloat.php

As you can see, when the list items is floated left with images for each, the width of each LI is the same as those without images. Why is that?

I've tried to troubleshoot this for quite some time, but I can't figure it out. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 I realize that, but the example page I linked to will remain online for others to see, which I've done for all my examples pages here on SO. As the end result may have been the result of the styling that my CMS create for my pages, it was more useful (for me) to get a solution that worked in that environment

Comment: _"which I've done for all my examples pages here on SO"_ Then you've been doing it wrong in all your other questions as well. Having your own site is fine, but first and foremost the code should always be in your question. Posting questions on SO isn't just about helping you, it's about helping the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a style as below in your Stylesheet

```
.text {
    float: left;
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I would have never guessed though, seems like a really odd "bug" in css... Why would I need to float the text to force it to count to the parents width? But anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `div` to `display: inline`, or better yet, use an inline element `<span>` instead of a block-level element `<div>` for the contents of your `<li>`, and make the image inline as well. Then the contents of the `<li>` will not have to be floated at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is setting the width of the li elements either.
If you haven't a fix try this:

```
ol div.text, ul div.text
{
 padding:6px;
 overflow:visible;
 min-height:14px;
 white-space:nowrap;
 min-width:80px;
}
```

I've just looked back on your linked page and it appears fixed on all my browsers though.